# How to make a DES s-box

Tags: cryptography, des

I am learning to program to implement DES encryption algorithm, But I met a problem:
In the DES cipher algorithm ,DES uses 8 S-boxes which each take in 6 bits and output 4 bits. And it is Already provided.

how can I make a S-box by myself. It only needs to meet two conditions:

1. Nonlinear
2. When the input changes by one bit, the output changes by at least two

I originally wanted to enumerate, and pick the right one, but it is too much calculation, and not realistic.

So how can I effective get a S-box? Can you provide some code or article？

I already checked a lot of information, So I need your help, thank you very much

Comment: This question is off-topic here, rather it belongs on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). But first make sure it hasn't already been answered there.

Answer (score 0):

S-box design is not easy. You will face problems;

Make sure that they are resistant to;

- Differential attacks
- Linear attacks
- Algebraic attacks

Some links for you Practical [S-Box Design](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/13b8/29756a9c956bda63fe256d902bf18ad71273.pdf) [The design of s-Boxes](https://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/bitstream/handle/10211.10/448/Cheung_Jennifer.pdf)

Feistel based cipher are old, Substitution-permutation network (SPN) is more common.